# Two Xcode app icons in launchpad after 4.5 install

Tags: xcode, macos

After updating Xcode via App Store, I now have 2 Xcode apps in my launchpad. I can delete the new one by holding my mouse button down and clicking the x that appears, but only for the new one.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is to head to your applications folder, (Using the menu bar, not a dock folder) and manually moving Xcode to your trash. After that, open launchpad and let it update. Both Xcodes will be gone. Then open your trash and right click Xcode, select Put Back. Voila, you fixed your problem and didn't even have to re-download!

Comment: I also had to reboot for it to remove the second icon, and then put it back.

Comment: For me, 2nd icon never left Launchpad even after reboot, but after putting back Xcode from Trash, the icons were not re-duplicated.

Comment: Please do not do just like me! Both of the two Xcode icon are the same version in my Mac. I've just moved the second Xcode icon from Launchpad to the Trash, and I try that first, that worked! But after a few minutes, My first Xcode missed!

Answer (score 16):

If moving the app to trash and back does not solve the problem, try this command in the Terminal **before** you move the app back from the trash:

```
killall Dock
```

Comment: In Ventura 13.5.2, `killall Dock` seems to work by itself without the Trash step.

Answer (score 3):

Run command  in terminal will reset launchpad, it works for me

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

**NOTE: This will reset arrangement of you apps order by  alphabetic.**

Comment: If you ResetLaunchPad you'll loose the arrangement of apps you had.